# How to iterate over a List<string> in jquery

Tags: jquery

Hi I have a function in my MVC controller returning a `IList<string>`.

I call it in jquery via:

```
$.post('Invoice/Validate/' + invoiceId, function(data) {
$.each(data, function(key, value) {
alert(value);
});
```

The problem is instead of getting the strings in the List I'm getting the letters out of System.String[] individually displayed by the alert.

Could somebody please point me in the right direction?

Comment: You need to fix your controller method to return the JSON array of string rather than .ToString() of the List<string>

Comment: Hey, thanks this solved it but needs to be answer to tick it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to fix your controller method to return the JSON array of string rather than .ToString() of the List